# CSS line-height transition issue in firefox (a bug?)

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

I tried making a header which becomes sticky when page is scrolled. Header has both `height`  and `line-height` animation as well which working fine Google Chrome but not Firefox 29.

The problem is the line-height transition + `position:fixed;`. I am adding a `.sticky` class to to header upon scrolling which has CSS `position: fixed;`

**Case 1**
http://jsfiddle.net/69uEx/3/ (this works fine in chrome. If you open it in firefox and manually change line-height property of H1 tag using firebug, you will see transition working).

**Case 2**
http://jsfiddle.net/4S6Kv/1/ (in this fiddle, I have change `.sticky` element's position to `position:static;` now the transition works in firefox. )

Seems the main culprit is `position:fixed;`

Any idea how to fix it? Line height transition is now working in FF.

Thanks

Comment: Most up to date (AFAICT) bug report on this issue: **https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289**